# How could i integrate github with android studio?

Tags: android-studio, github

I tried to integrate Github through VCS->version control system.It gives following error,when i click on fix it,the 2nd window opens.Now i am clueless that what to do?[image: This error comes on right side]

[image: After clicking fix it,this window opens]

kindly help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give the full path to the git.exe, not just the name. Browse to the directory where you installed it and select executable from there.

Comment: Thank you.it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to specify the full path eg. `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\got.exe`.

In addition to providing the appropriate login details in the **`Git-hub`** section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install git. After installing & configuring git, open android studio, Go to "VCS", then-> "Import into version control", then-> "Share project on github". Give your github username & password, create a github master password for android studio & start sharing your project on github.